# In Hazelcast jet how can we store IList to normal list as I have to sent it in Response?

Tags: java, hazelcast, hazelcast-jet

I am new to Hazelcast jet and in my application on data I am doing some aggregation and getting data but I want to send that in rest response so how can I change it to normal list?

```
public class ResponseMessage<T> {

private T responseClassType;

private ResponseMessage() {}
private ResponseMessage(T t) {
    this.responseClassType = t;
}

public static <T> ResponseMessage<T> withResponseData(T classType) {
    return new ResponseMessage<T>(classType);
}

   public static ResponseMessage<Void> empty() {
        return new ResponseMessage<>();
    }

public T getResponseClassType() {
    return responseClassType;
}

public void setResponseClassType(T responseClassType) {
    this.responseClassType = responseClassType;
}


}
```

This is my generic response class and as below I am sending response after all calculations:

```
public ResponseMessage<?> runProcess(Pipeline pl) {
    Map<String, BatchStage<Object>> allBatch = new HashMap<String,BatchStage<Object>>();
    allBatch.put(z.get("id").toString(), new SomeCalulation().readSource(pipeline));
    BatchStage<Object> h = allBatch.values().iterator().next();
    h.writeTo(Sinks.list("abc"));
                         
    IList<Object> abc = jetInstance.getList("abc");
    List<Object> result = new ArrayList(abc);
    abc.destroy();
                          
    return ResponseMessage.withResponseData(result);
  }
```

Now this is working but everytime I call rest request it is increasing the list and if I clear the list it is showing blank records, please help how can I convert it to normal list or best way to send response?

It was not working because I was joining it after method call:

```
runProcess(pl);
job.join(); // so because I am joining it after runProcess not working but if I directly return ResponseMessage.withResponseData(jetInstance.getList("abc")); and then join it will work.
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see submitting the pipeline as a job and waiting for the result (`job.join()`). I suppose you have omitted this from your code sample.

To solve your issue with empty list simply copy the result before destroying the list:

```
job.join();

IList<Object> abc = jetInstance.getList("abc");
List<Object> result = new ArrayList(abc)
abc.destroy();
return ResponseMessage.withResponseData(result);
```

Also, the list should have a unique name for each request, otherwise, multiple requests will write to the same list, having unpredictable results.

Comment: there is no such method destroy and if I use clear it clears all the list may be because they are sync and gives blank list.

Comment: Right, the destroy method is on the IList interface.

Comment: If this doesn't work for you then please provide full reproducible example.

Comment: nope, I think it is destroying result also and it is sending empty list.

Comment: Are you sure the list contains anything before you make the copy? (`List<Object> result = new ArrayList(abc)`) Your updated code still doesn't submit any job.

Comment: yes because if I using return ResponseMessage.withResponseData(jetInstance.getList("abc"));  it works but list keeps increasing

Comment: Can't help you more unless you provide [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Sorry my fault you are right, to make it work with local List I have to join before and in my case I was joining after so it was working with  return ResponseMessage.withResponseData(jetInstance.getList("abc")); but not with local :)